# Python script to duplicate .tex files with small changes

Tags: python, scripting, latex

I have a letter in LaTeX format. I'd like to write a short script in python that takes one argument (the addressee) and creates a .tex file with the general letter format and the addressee.

```
    from sys import argv
    script, addressee = argv
    file = open('newletter.tex', 'w')
    file.write("\begin{Document} Dear " + addressee + ", \n Greetings, how are you? Sincerely, Me \end{Document}")
    file.close()
```

Is there a better function to write out large blocks of text? Also, you can see that the .tex file will contain programming syntax - will python disregard this as long as it is coerced to a string? Do I need to coerce a large block to string? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean *"the .tex file will contain programming syntax"*? Can you give a (small) example of the contents of a file?

Answer (score 1):

If you directly enter `print "\begin..."` into your interpreter, you will notice the result will omit the `\b` on the front of the string.  This is because `\b` is a character that the print statement (or function if you're in 3.x) recognizes (it happens to be a backspace).

To avoid this confusion, you can use a "raw string", which in python is denoted by pre-pending an 'r':

```
>>> a = "\begin"
>>> b = r"\begin"
>>> print a
egin
>>> print b
\begin
>>>
```

Typically, when working with strings to represent file paths, or anything else which may contain a `\` character, you should use a raw string.

As far as inserting information into a template, I would recommend using the `format()` function rather than string concatenation.  To do this, your string would look like this:

```
r"\begin{{Document}} Dear {} \n Greetings, how are you? Sincerely, Me \end{{Document}}".format(addressee)
```

The argument of the function (in this case `addressee`) will be inserted into each `{}` within the string.  For this reason, curly brackets which should be interpreted literally must be escaped by included them in duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take the approach of creating the tex files first  as letter.tex  with the addressee set to something like QXQ_ADDRESSEE_QXQ.

The in the python script I'd read the entire file into memory.  When you read from a file, it gets treated as a raw string with proper escaping.

```
with open('letter.tex', 'r') as f:
   raw_letter = f.readlines()
```

Then just do a substitution and write the string to a file.

```
raw_letter.replace("QXQ_ADDRESSEE_QXQ", newname)
with open('newletter.tex', 'w') as f:
  f.write(raw_letter)
```